# How to update xml file using python beautifulsoup

Tags: python, xml, beautifulsoup

I have a xml file for which I have to update a value of tag. Below is the content of the file

```
<annotation>
    <folder>train</folder>
    <filename>Arms1.jpg</filename>
    <path>D:\PyCharmWorkSpace\Tensorflow\workspace\training_demo\images\train\Arms1.jpg</path>
    <source>
        <database>Unknown</database>
    </source>
</annotation>
```

In the above content, I have to update the value of `path` with new valueBelow is the code I have:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import os

curr_dir = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'img')
files = os.listdir(curr_dir)

for file in files:
    if ".xml" in file:
        file_path = os.path.join(curr_dir, file)
        with open(file_path, 'r') as f:
            xml_data = f.read()
        bs_data = BeautifulSoup(xml_data, "xml")
        bs_data.path.string = "C:\"
        xml_file = open(file_path, "w")
        xml_file.write(bs_data.prettify())
```

But its not getting updated in xml file. Can anyone please help. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using ElementTree (no need for any external lib)

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET


xml = '''<annotation>
    <folder>train</folder>
    <filename>Arms1.jpg</filename>
    <path>D:\PyCharmWorkSpace\Tensorflow\workspace\training_demo\images\train\Arms1.jpg</path>
    <source>
        <database>Unknown</database>
    </source>
</annotation>'''

root = ET.fromstring(xml)
root.find('path').text = 'new path value goes here'
ET.dump(root)
```

output

```
<annotation>
    <folder>train</folder>
    <filename>Arms1.jpg</filename>
    <path>new path value goes here</path>
    <source>
        <database>Unknown</database>
    </source>
</annotation>
```

Comment: Why have you mentioned `.//path`. I meant to say what does `.//` means here. Can we not simply use `path`?

Comment: @SAndrew I thought `path` is nested deeper. But this is not the case so `.//` is not required :-). Code was fixed. Feel free to accept the answer. See https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#supported-xpath-syntax in order to see what `//` means